# Find linear equation given single y value and the gradient

Tags: linear-algebra

As mentioned by the title, I am trying to find a full linear equation given a y value and a gradient.
In this single question I am given this information.
"Frederick the electrician charges his customers a standard call out fee plus a certain amount per hour. For a job that takes him $3$ hours he charges $220$ and for a job that takes him $7$ hours, he charges $480.$ Write a rule in standard linear form."
So can anybody help me?

Comment: You aren't just given a $y$ value and gradient. You are given the gradient with two $(x,y)$ pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradient = (480 - 220)/4 = $65/hour

For a straight line, y = mx + c

Therefore,

y = 65x + c

Also we know when x = 3, y = 220, thus

220 = 65*3 + c

Thus c = 220 - 195

Thus c = 25

Therefore

y = 65x + 25

Comment: Could you explain the (480-220)/4, where does the 4 come from, and why do we subtract the 480 from 220? Thanks for the extremely prompt reply.

Comment: This is a good job for the eletrician and a good answer from you !

Comment: @KobeyRafferty, gradient = rise/run.  We are given two coordinates (3 hours, 220) and (7 hours, 480).  Rise = 480 - 220 and Run = 7-3 = 4.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @Mew Sure does, didn't think about that. Thanks alot! Will mark as solved as soon as I can!

Comment: @KobeyRafferty Thanks Bro

Comment: @Dhruv I see you tried to edit my answer, but in the process the $ sign dropped off from $65 per hour.  If you are going to make changes, please ensure units are removed in the process.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is good but I would like to include another great idea. It's called the point slope form of a linear equation in two variables.

We know,

$$\text{gradient } = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = 65$$

Now we have a solution $(3, 220)$.

The point slope form is:

$$y-y_1 = m(x-x_1) \text{ where } (x_1, y_1) \text{ is a solution}$$

So, we can write it as:

$$y - 220 = 65(x-3)$$

On solving this you get:

$$y=65x-195$$

Comment: Thanks for this method as well!